# When 'Select All' Parameter ticked all data is not showing

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

This is a glimpse of what my report look likes, a series of charts, where you can select a country and a date range of either 12 months rolling or 36 months rolling.

The report is working ok in regards to selecting one country and seeing the different data within the 12 or 36 months date range.

[image]

The problem comes when I 'Select All' countries.  What I want is the totals of all the countries to be represented on the graphs.  As you see below, with all countries selected the data on the graph has not changed from the image above.

[image]

The Country parameter

[image]

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [name] @Country VARCHAR(max)
    ,@DateRange VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN


        SELECT country
            ,[yyyy-mm]
            ,[12Months]
            ,[36Months]
            ,[Population]
            ,[Employed]
        FROM (
            SELECT CASE [countryID]
                    WHEN '800002'
                        THEN 'UK'
                    WHEN '800003'
                        THEN 'France'
                    WHEN '800004'
                        THEN 'Germany'
                    ELSE 'N/A'
                    END AS country
                ,Convert(CHAR(7), [DateTimeOfCall], 121) "yyyy-mm"
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN datetimeofcall BETWEEN Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, - 12, current_timestamp)), 0)
                            AND Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, 0, current_timestamp)), 0)
                        THEN 'y'
                    ELSE 'n'
                    END AS [12Months]
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN datetimeofcall BETWEEN Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, - 36, current_timestamp)), 0)
                            AND Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, 0, current_timestamp)), 0)
                        THEN 'y'
                    ELSE 'n'
                    END AS [36Months]
                ,sum(CASE 
                        WHEN [CategoryID] = '180003'
                            AND [CauseID] IN (
                                '700002'
                                ,'700003'
                                )
                            AND [TypeID] = '100002'
                            AND [PopTypeID] BETWEEN '170002'
                                AND '170019'
                            THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                        END) Population
                ,sum(CASE 
                        WHEN [EmpID] = '210002'
                            THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Employed
            FROM [dbo].[country]
            WHERE STATUS = '1'
            GROUP BY [countryID]
                ,Convert(CHAR(7), [DateTimeOfCall], 121)
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN datetimeofcall BETWEEN Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, - 12, current_timestamp)), 0)
                            AND Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, 0, current_timestamp)), 0)
                        THEN 'y'
                    ELSE 'n'
                    END
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN datetimeofcall BETWEEN Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, - 36, current_timestamp)), 0)
                            AND Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, 0, current_timestamp)), 0)
                        THEN 'y'
                    ELSE 'n'
                    END
            ) a



    WHERE country in (@country)
        AND (
            (
                @DateRange = 12
                AND [12Months] = 'Y'
                )
            OR (
                @DateRange = 36
                AND [36Months] = 'Y'
                )
            )


END
```

And this is what the output is

```
country        yyyy-mm      Population   Employed     12months      36months

  uk           2016-06        56            43           y             y
  france       2016-06        40            22           y             y
  Germany      2016-06        73            32           y             y
  uk           2015-06        45            10           n             y
  france       2015-06        30            11           n             y
  Germany      2015-06        76            56           n             y
   AND SO ON......
```

All help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: With the option `All` you have to convert the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE country IN (@country)` because SSRS returns a comma-separated list of values. What determines the grouping/series of the charts? What are the values?

Comment: In the first chart for example the value is set as [sum(Population)], category group is yyyy-mm and I have nothing in the series group

Comment: Is it me or are you outputting `country` as `NSDG`, `ESDG` and `WSDG`?

Comment: Have you tried my first suggestion for the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: sorry, yes I did but it made no effect

Comment: You could try adding a table with the same values and see if it contains the values you expect?

Comment: First why are you messing around with temp tables? Just select the data in the stored procedure. Second, @NickyvV suggestion should work. Are you perhaps defining your parameter list with the values of the CountryID, and forgetting you've used a case statement to resolve the name?

Comment: thanks for the advice Paul have made the changes and edited my code  above.  Assuming you mean the out put Nicky pointed out above regarding ESDG,NSDG etc out put, then no that is not the issue.

Comment: What will be value Country if you select '(SELECT ALL)'

Comment: You have to convert @Country to a table of values or parse it into a proper IN comparison. IN '1,2,3,4,5,6' will not work.

Comment: How are the values in the country parameter defined? Are they hard-coded or from a query?

Comment: I have specified the values in the parameter